# TCPClient returns 400 most of times

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, tcp, tcpclient

I am creating a TCP connection in C# to some mp3 stream using HTTP to analyze a request. 
When I open the connection, I always close it using

```
tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
tcpClient.Close();
```

I also tried to use:

```
client.Client.Disconnect(false);
```

If I run my app again and re-connect, I receive 400 (Bad Request) and connection-close in response header, even though I see using "netstat" that the connection does not exist anymore.
This is the code I have so far:

```
string headers = new string [] {
                    "GET /stream HTTP/1.0", 
                    "Host: sci.streamingmurah.com:8032", 
                    "Connection: keep-alive", 
                    "Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0", 
                    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36", 
                    "Accept: */*",
                    "Referer: 82.XX.XX.XX", 
                    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6"
            };
try
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        client.SendTimeout = 5000;
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
        client.Connect(host, port);
        using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
        {

            foreach (string requestHeader in headers)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Request Header: " + requestHeader);

                byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestHeader);
                ns.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);
                ns.WriteByte(13);
                ns.WriteByte(10);
            }

            ns.WriteByte(13);
            ns.WriteByte(10);

            List<string> responseHeaders = new List<string>();

            string responseHeader;
            while (Utils.ReadLine(ns, Encoding.ASCII, out responseHeader) && responseHeader.Length > 0)
            {
                responseHeaders.Add(responseHeader);
            }
            //Response headers contains 
            if (responseHeaders.Count == 0)
            {
                traceInfo.AddLine(TraceInfo.EntryKind.Alert, "Response is empty");
                client.GetStream().Close();
                client.Close();
                //client.Client.Disconnect(false);
                return null;
            }

            Playable pl = HandleResponse(responseHeaders.ToArray(), ns);
            client.GetStream().Close();
            client.Close();
            return pl;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    traceInfo.AddLine(TraceInfo.EntryKind.Alert, String.Format("Exception: {0}", e.Message));
}

return null;
```

Of course - if I run the stream in Chrome, it always works. So something I'm doing must be wrong.
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe because of missing `Content-Length`. ( Why don't you simply use WebClient or HttpClient)

Comment: @L.B: This is a GET request. It does not have content and thus no Content-Length header is used (browser don't do this either).

Answer (score 1):

You send the content of each line and each `\r` and `\n` each in its own `Write`. This way the request might be spread over multiple TCP packets which is in theory not a problem - since TCP is just a data stream without implicit message boundaries. But, some experiments show that this is actually a problem in this case: If one sends the request within a single write (which results in a single packet) it will work, if it is spread over multiple writes like in your case it will result in `400 Bad Request`.

My guess is that there is some protection either in front of the web server or inside the server which tries to detect DOS attacks like [Slowloris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)) where the attacker spreads the HTTP request over many packets with lots of delay in between. Although you don't do such an attack the behavior caused by your code (request spread over multiple packets) might trigger this DOS detection which then rejects the request early.

The fix would be not to write each part of the request header immediately to the socket but instead collect everything inside some internal buffer and send this buffer then inside a single write to the socket.

Comment: That was a perfect answer! I added all headers into a StringBuilder, then wrote everything at once. It worked very well. Thank you!!